# IguanaTex ttfonts.map Missing

Tags: miktex2.9

I am just starting to use Latex in windows 10.I've installed MikTex 2.9,updated it today and installed the IguanaTex AddIn for MS PowerPoint 2007.However every time I type a latex code on IguanaTex and click the generate button I get the following error message:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/82GM6.jpg)
Then as I enter debug mode these two
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBxXT.jpg)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y84OJ.jpg)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK3Mz.jpg)
And every time I close IguanaTex and again type something this repeats and each time I need to install the ttfonts.map etc.Now I searched it on the internet and learnt that it is a MikTex issue.So let me clear some points:
There was no option to customise the MikTex install.I did not touch anything on the setup.
I updated it today.The issue was not resolved.
On MikTex Console the package Zhmetrics is shown as installed but I couldn't find something like ttfonts.I tried to locate the file but couldn't.The MikTex setup log shows no error and the MikTex font log has no "ttfont" installed or something like that.
These error is not listed on the IguanaTex developer page nor on MikTex.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I added an issue for the miktex problem: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/298. I have some doubts that you really need a ttfonts.map, so you could try to put an empty file of this name in `some-root-folder\fonts\map\`, and then add `some-root-folder` as a new root in the miktex console.

Comment: The miktex maintainer wrote that ttfonts.map should be in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\ttf2pk\. Do you have it?

Comment: The ttf fonts are often system fonts as used by windows zhmetrics are CJK fonts that may not be as well supported by MiKTeX/TeX Live compared to w32tex however there may be alternative options see https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit/tree/master/zhmetrics the key with MiKTeX is ensuring you repeatedly update font mapping (MiKTeX-console > tasks) at both user and if necessary at MiKTeX admin level. it is also important to check dvipng is correctly configured on a "normal" path.  `where $path:dvipng` should confirm it is functional